# eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes. Only got 20 bytes

Tags: hardhat, gnosis-safe

I would like to play with `safe-cli` (at commit [6d440943c08d31bf68f8f6e7a6c67c71938a6caa](https://github.com/5afe/safe-cli/commit/6d440943c08d31bf68f8f6e7a6c67c71938a6caa)) on a local development chain. I don't know how to solve this error and I am stuck.

Set up with safe-contracts and hardhat:

```
$ cd safe-contracts/
$ yarn hardhat --network hardhat deploy
$ yarn hardhat node
```

Then in a new terminal (this private key is well-known don't worry)

```
$ safe-creator http://localhost:8545 0x1ab42cc412b618bdea3a599e3c9bae199ebf030895b039e9db1e30dafb12b727 --proxy-factory 0x914d7Fec6aaC8cd542e72Bca78B30650d45643d7 --safe-contract 0x654a3298C9C0E319094a62034dbe87D7336310E3 --callback-handler 0x92E6f1002fA3ac7239f958b4A9f9cE297b780AF5
```

The error is [in this gist.](https://gist.github.com/lourkeur/559331166a4c48e3073b50dcc8922c72)

[createProxyWithNonce](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/proxies/SafeProxyFactory.sol#L46) should return the address of a newly-created Safe which is a proxy contract. What's happening and what can I do?